# Is there any way to Set border to Button in ROKU?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I add two buttons in ROKU like belove.

[image]

and I tied to display border with a button like belove.

[image]

I show YuppTV like belove But I don't know what component that used to display like that. But I tried to the same thing in Button.

[image]

Is there any way to Set a border to button in ROKU. and remove a bullet in Button.

Comment: The YuppTV example you mentioned is probably using a `RowList`, which offers more customisation through custom components. You might want to look into a `MarkupList` to achieve what you want, rather than simply using `Button` components.

Comment: @Thenaz Thank you for your answer I tried with markup But Is there any way with button component.

Comment: I created an image and Set image on Button using focusFootprintBitmapUri and focusBitmapUri. Its work for me. But Its looks like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no a native way, you should create a custom component and place four rectangles around the element.

```
rectTop=createObject("roSGNode", "Rectangle")
rectTop.width = element.width
rectTop.height = 2
rectTop.translation = [0, 0]

rectBottom=createObject("roSGNode", "Rectangle")
rectBottom.width = element.width
rectBottom.height = 2
rectBottom.translation = [0, element.height - rectBottom.height]

rectLeft=createObject("roSGNode", "Rectangle")
rectLeft.width = 2
rectLeft.height = element.height
rectLeft.translation = [0, 0]

rectRight=createObject("roSGNode", "Rectangle")
rectRight.width = 2
rectRight.height = element.height
rectRight.translation = [element.width - rectRight.width, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But YuppTV used to some component do these. I Edit my Post. Pls, check my Post.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buttons to the Markuplist and use `drawFocusFeedback = "true"` to show the focus border and `focusBitmapBlendColor` to specify the color

Answer (score 0):

I never use buttons. I Always makey my own button component,asitmakesthis kind of thing and many others way eaaier.

@veronicas rectangle hack is neat, and appropriate in your case, and would make a good component (if you haven't done already).

A more robust solution, imo, would be an image based one where you:

- make a custom poster component
- which check for the 9 patch on cachefs (named with border inset and width as a key)
- and if it isn't there, draw it on the fly via a task.

That will give you the opportunity to make arbitrary inset patch 9 rectangles with any border width, that support rounded corners, whenever you need.